# Dropdown Options to show only one from same class of option

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue. To show only 1 from the same class.
My Dropdown Codes are as following.

```
<select id="AgeSelect" class="nf" name="ages">
<option value="">Filter By Age Group</option>
<option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
<option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
<option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
<option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
<option value="14 Years and Under" class="14YearsandUnder">14 Years and Under</option>
<option value="14 Years and Under" class="14YearsandUnder">14 Years and Under</option>
<option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
<option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
<option value="12 Years and Under" class="12YearsandUnder">12 Years and Under</option>
<option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
<option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
<option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
<option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
<option value="12 Years and Under" class="12YearsandUnder">12 Years and Under</option>
<option value="12 Years and Under" class="12YearsandUnder">12 Years and Under</option>
<option value="8 Years and Under" class="8YearsandUnder">8 Years and Under</option>
<option value="8 Years and Under" class="8YearsandUnder">8 Years and Under</option>
<option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
<option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
<option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
<option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
<option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
<option value="Special Needs" class="SpecialNeeds">Special Needs</option>
<option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
<option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
<option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
<option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
<option value="Special Needs" class="SpecialNeeds">Special Needs</option>
</select>
```

You can see all the classes in Options.

like `class="10YearsandUnder"` , `class="14YearsandUnder"`.
I have tried CSS First Selector but I am failed.

Kindly help me to make this done.

What I need is, Only to show one from same classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below code to your `<script>` tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const distinctClasses = new Set();

    $('#AgeSelect').find('option').each(function(){
        if(this.className != "") {
            distinctClasses.add(this.className);
        }
    });

    distinctClasses.forEach(cls => {
        $(`option.${cls}`).slice(1).hide();
    });
});
```

Make sure to don't use fat arrow functions where `this` is used as it might change the value of `this`.

Comment: The `remove()` method removes the selected elements, including all text and child nodes. I'm not sure if OP wants that. Let OP decide what he wants.

Comment: But in Safari Browser it not works. can you suggest me some thing about that @KartikChauhan

Comment: Seems like hide() doesn't work in few versions of Safari. In that case you can replace `$(\`option.${cls}\`).slice(1).hide();` with `$(\`option.${cls}\`).slice(1).css('display', 'none');` or `$(\`option.${cls}\`).slice(1).remove();` based on your requirement.

Comment: @KartikChauhan, Thank you so much, It worked perfect now On Safari. 
.remove() worked Good on Safari

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by looping over all the options and maintaining a map of `class` names. If the `class` is not present on the map then add it, else hide the option.

```js
var classList = {};
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#AgeSelect option');
options.forEach(function(option) {
  if (option.className) {
    classList[option.className] ? option.style.display = 'none' : classList[option.className] = "done"
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="AgeSelect" class="nf" name="ages">
  <option value="">Filter By Age Group</option>
  <option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
  <option value="14 Years and Under" class="14YearsandUnder">14 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="14 Years and Under" class="14YearsandUnder">14 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="12 Years and Under" class="12YearsandUnder">12 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="12 Years and Under" class="12YearsandUnder">12 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="12 Years and Under" class="12YearsandUnder">12 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="8 Years and Under" class="8YearsandUnder">8 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="8 Years and Under" class="8YearsandUnder">8 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years and Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years and Under</option>
  <option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
  <option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
  <option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
  <option value="Special Needs" class="SpecialNeeds">Special Needs</option>
  <option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
  <option value="10 Years &amp; Under" class="10YearsandUnder">10 Years &amp; Under</option>
  <option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
  <option value="Open Age" class="OpenAge">Open Age</option>
  <option value="Special Needs" class="SpecialNeeds">Special Needs</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OP need jQuery solution. Question has no tag of Javascript - Just FYI.

Comment: Did not notice it earlier. However as jQuery solutions are already posted, i will just leave it here in case it is helpful to someone.